# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using stringWithFormat?

Tags: ios, xcode

While deploying my application, I got the error message: "Thread 1:Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

My code is below:

```
-(NSDictionary *)syncWithList:(NSInteger)listID
{
    NSString *urlit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/%@/syncList.json?auth_token=%@",@"xxxxxxxxxxx",listID];
// **Here I got the error message: "Thread 1:Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"**
    NSLog(@"url: %@",urlit);
    NSURL *freequestionurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlit];
    ASIHTTPRequest *back = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:freequestionurl];
    [back startSynchronous];
    self.listData = [[back responseString] objectFromJSONString];
    NSLog(@"%@",listData);
    NSDictionary *dicPost = [listData objectAtIndex:0];
    return dicPost;
}
```

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Not a code review site! "EXC BAD ACCESS" usually means that someone (i.e. you) made a mistake and are using a pointer not correctly allocated, etc. The is effectively the C version of a NPE or NRE.

Comment: @pst thanks for your reply, I knew the meaning of "EXC BAD ACCESS", but I didn't find any wrong pointer or release error at all. I also did a lot of research on both Google and Stack overflow, and I didn't get the info I need, so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: My comment was "*gravity exists*". The answer is just as I was expecting.

Comment: @pst: thanks, I mixed the two arguments up.

Comment: You can type the string with arguments in NSLog and it will usually suggest you the correct format specifiers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must not format `NSInteger` (which is just a typedef'd `int` on current iOS versions) with the `%@` specifier. Writing `%@` in a string format basically means "call `description` on the object and use the result".
But NSInteger is not an object, it's a primitive type.
You get a memory exception because when listID is 42 you access an object at memory address 42. This is definitely not what you want.

```
-(NSDictionary *)syncWithList:(NSInteger)listID
                               ^^^^^^^^^
NSString *urlit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/%@/syncList.json?auth_token=%@",@"xxxxxxxxxxx",listID];
                                                                                                     ^^
```

just use the `%i` format specifier instead of `%@` for listID.

```
NSString *urlit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/%@/syncList.json?auth_token=%i",@"xxxxxxxxxxx",listID];
```

Comment: Now that I actually read the address I think you got the arguments mixed up. `http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/xxxxxxxxxxx/syncList.json?auth_token=42` is what you get with that format.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: So used to getting errors from Xcode without it giving me any clues I neglected to notice that the troubled line was already know. I'll leave this here in the hope it helps someone in future.

Try creating an exception breakpoint, it may point to straight to the line where your code is falling over which should help you figure out the problem.

1. Switch to the breakpoint 'tab' in the left hand navigator.
2. Click the little '+' at the bottom.
3. Create a breakpoint as shown in the image:
4. Run your code and see where it pops.

[image: Breakpoint adding]

Comment: Thanks! I already knew the code with error below:
NSString *urlit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/%@/syncList.json?auth_token=%@",@"xxxxxxxxxxx",listID];
**I got the error message: "Thread 1:Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"**
However I didn't see any wrong with it. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong data type to print out.

```
NSLog(@"%@",listData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You made very popularar mistake in this line

```
NSString *urlit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/%@/syncList.json?auth_token=%@",@"xxxxxxxxxxx",listID];
```

Second argument is of type NSInteger, but in format you use `%@`, this is object only, and compiler thinks that your listID is address of object.
Correct format is `%li`:

```
NSString *urlit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/lists/%@/syncList.json?auth_token=%li",@"xxxxxxxxxxx",listID];
```